# Ruby JSON parse "sub-keys"?

Tags: json, ruby, parsing

I'm trying to parse an additional key to an existing JSON that I've been parsing for some time, but recently we add a new key "metric_details" that seperate individual areas, this contains 2 keys as well "performance_score", and "compliance_score". Now, I've been able to parse this without issue, but can't figure out for the life of me how to pull the metric_details out and also export the scores into my RDS.

**Parse Code:**

```
   states = %w(CA TX)
results_warehouses = states
creds = User_creds

data_to_write = []
results_warehouses.each do |code|

  dashboard = "https://sample.website.com/states/scorecard.json?state_id=#{code}"
  puts "Pulling from #{dashboard}"

  begin
    data  =  HTTParty.get(dashboard, :basic_auth=> {:username => creds.public.text, :password => creds.private.text})
  rescue
    puts "Could not fetch data for #{code}. Skipping..."
    next
  end

  types = %w(pack ship)
  types.each do |type|

    metric = data[type]
    next if metric.nil?
    metric.sort.each do |key|
      state_id                = key['state_id']
      raw_date                = key['date'].to_date
      # Can't figure how to parse this metric_details          = key['metric_details']
      performance_score       = key['performance_score']
      audit_compliance_score  = key['compliance_score']

      data_to_write << "('#{state_id.to_s}',
                         '#{raw_date.to_s}',
                         '#{type.to_s}',
                         '#{metric_details.to_s}',
                         '#{performance_score.to_s}',
                         '#{compliance_score.to_s}')"
      puts data_to_write
    end
  end

  unless data_to_write.empty?
    puts 'Inserting data'
    db_conn   = DatabaseConnect.new
    db_client = db_conn.connect_mysql
    ins = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `data`.`scoring` VALUES #{data_to_write.join(',')}"
    db_client.query(ins)
  end
  db_conn.disconnect
  puts 'Completed.'
end

puts 'All done!'
```

**And, here is the JSON I'm pulling apart, which has no issues, until I try to grab the individual metric details**

```
"pack":[
{
"state_id":"CA",
"total_score":90,
"compliance_score":100,
"performance_score":80,
"date":"2016-11-24T00:00:00.000-08:00",
"metric_details":{
"Damages":{
"performance_score":91,
"compliance_score":100
},
"Error Indicators":{
"performance_score":100,
"compliance_score":"N/A"
},
"Unverified":{
"performance_score":75,
"compliance_score":100
},
"Pack Miss":{
"performance_score":54,
"ompliance_score":100
}
}
}
],
```

**And my table structure is fairly simple:**

**And essentially wanted to format as such:**

CA, 2016-11-25, pack, Damages, 75, 100

state_id, raw_date, type, metric_details, performance_score, compliance_score

Thank you for the help!

**Updated:**

```
states = %w(CA TX)
results_warehouses = states
creds = User_creds

data_to_write = []
results_warehouses.each do |code|

  dashboard = "https://sample.website.com/states/scorecard.json?state_id=#{code}"
  puts "Pulling from #{dashboard}"

  begin
    data  =  HTTParty.get(dashboard, :basic_auth=> {:username => creds.public.text, :password => creds.private.text})
  rescue
    puts "Could not fetch data for #{code}. Skipping..."
    next
  end

  types = %w(pack ship)
  types.each do |type|

    metric = data[type]
    next if metric.nil?
    metric.sort.each do |key|
      state_id                = key['state)ud']
      raw_date                = key['date'].to_date
      hash                    = key['metric_details']
      damages                 = hash['Damages']
      performance_score       = damages['performance_score']
      audit_compliance_score  = damages['compliance_score']

      data_to_write << "('#{state_id.to_s}',
                         '#{raw_date.to_s}',
                         '#{type.to_s}',
                         '#{metric_details.to_s}',
                         '#{performance_score.to_s}',
                         '#{audit_compliance_score.to_s}')"
      puts data_to_write
    end
  end

  unless data_to_write.empty?
    puts 'Inserting data'
    db_conn   = DatabaseConnect.new
    db_client = db_conn.connect_mysql
    ins = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `data`.`scoring` VALUES #{data_to_write.join(',')}"
    db_client.query(ins)
  end
  db_conn.disconnect
  puts 'Completed.'
end

puts 'All done!'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key['metric_details']` returns the hash:

```
{
  "Damages":{
    "performance_score":91,
    "compliance_score":100
  },
  "Error Indicators": {
    "performance_score":100,
    "compliance_score":"N/A"
  },
  ...
  ...
}
```

So, you need to look up the info in that hash:

```
hash = key['metric_details']
damages = hash['Damages']
performance_score = damages['performance_score']
compliance_score = damgages['compliance_score']
```

Here is a full example:

```
require 'json'

data = %Q{
{"pack":[
{
"state_id": "CA",
"total_score":90,
"compliance_score":100,
"performance_score":80,
"date":"2016-11-24T00:00:00.000-08:00",
"metric_details":{
"Damages":{
"performance_score":91,
"compliance_score":100
},
"Error Indicators":{
"performance_score":100,
"compliance_score":"N/A"
},
"Unverified":{
"performance_score":75,
"compliance_score":100
},
"Pack Miss":{
"performance_score":54,
"ompliance_score":100
}
}
}
]

}
}

data = JSON.parse data
data_to_write = ""

types = %w(pack ship)
types.each do |type|
  metric = data[type]
  next if metric.nil?

  metric.sort.each do |hash|
    state_id                = hash['state_id']
    raw_date                = hash['date']
    # Can't figure how to parse this metric_details          = key['metric_details']
    #performance_score       = key['performance_score']
    #audit_compliance_score  = key['compliance_score']
    metric_details = hash['metric_details']
    damages_hash = metric_details['Damages']
    performance_score = damages_hash['performance_score']
    compliance_score = damages_hash['compliance_score']

    data_to_write << "('#{state_id}',
                       '#{raw_date}',
                       '#{type}',
                       '#{performance_score}',
                       '#{compliance_score}')"
    puts data_to_write
  end
end

--output:--
('CA',
                       '2016-11-24T00:00:00.000-08:00',
                       'pack',
                       '91',
                       '100')
```

Comment: Can this be implemented in the inital loop?

next if metric.nil?
    metric.sort.each do |key|
      warehouse_id            = key['warehouse_id']
      raw_date                = key['date'].to_date
      hash                    = key['metric_details']
      damages                 = hash['Damages']
      performance_score       = damages['performance_score']
      audit_compliance_score  = damages['compliance_score']

Comment: @Spartacus38, I think you can just put that code where your comment is, and delete the two lines under the comment.

Comment: lib/script/metric_details.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `metric_details' for main:Object (NameError)
        from lib/script/metric_details.rb:27:in `each'
        from lib/script/metric_details.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from lib/script/metric_details.rb:23:in `each'
        from lib/script/metric_details.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from lib/script/metric_details.rb:7:in `each'
        from lib/script/metric_details.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: I updated my code in the Updated section. I am getting this error while trying to put it in the same place of the comment. Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: @Spartacus38, I posted an example at the end of my answer.

Comment: Sweet, I was nearly there on my iteration, is there any way to loop multiple values, ie. Damages, Unverified to pull at once?

Comment: If you know all the key names, then you can just look them up in the hash, e.g. `metric_details['Damages'], metric_details['Unverified'], etc.`  If you don't know all the key names, then how do you loop over the key/value pairs in a hash like metric_details?

Comment: Yeah, I will know all the key names. So, lucky for that. I added ths.

hash              = metric_details['Damages'], metric_details['Pack Miss']

But, receive error: 
metric_scores.rb:48:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: This got me to my final conclusion. Thank you.